# Jssor. autoplay issues. no sir it is my issues, not jssor

Tags: slider, autoplay, jssor

Jssor Autoplay doesn't work. It works after drag or arrow navigation, but doesnt work when the page is loaded.

I get some errors in the Chrome console:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot scale jssor slider, 'height' of 'outer
>   container' not valid. 'height' of 'outer container' should be positive
>   number. e.g. 'height: 300px;' jssor.core.js:68 2 Consider using 'dppx'
>   units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not
>   dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of
>   a screen. In media query expression: only screen and
>   (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and
>   (min-resolution: 144dpi)

Checked everywhere, and height is 300px everywhere. Didn't even touched the JS. All settings are made in configs and the site admin panel. Outer container, as I understand are correct:

```
<div id="slider1_container">
  <div u="slides" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; width: 990px; height: 300px; top: 135px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
```

slider config:

```
<script>
        jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
            var options = { $AutoPlay: true };
            var _SlideshowTransitions = [
            //Swing Outside in Stairs
            {$Duration: 1200, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 8, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 9, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InWave, $Top: $Jease$.$InWave, $Clip: $Jease$.$OutQuad }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.2, $ScaleVertical: 0.1, $Outside: true, $Round: { $Left: 1.3, $Top: 2.5} }

            //Dodge Dance Outside out Stairs
            , { $Duration: 1500, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 8, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.1, 0.9], $Top: [0.1, 0.9] }, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 9, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InJump, $Top: $Jease$.$InJump, $Clip: $Jease$.$OutQuad }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $ScaleVertical: 0.3, $Outside: true, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }

            //Dodge Pet Outside in Stairs
            , { $Duration: 1500, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 8, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 9, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InWave, $Top: $Jease$.$InWave, $Clip: $Jease$.$OutQuad }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.2, $ScaleVertical: 0.1, $Outside: true, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }

            //Dodge Dance Outside in Random
            , { $Duration: 1500, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 8, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 9, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InJump, $Top: $Jease$.$InJump, $Clip: $Jease$.$OutQuad }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $ScaleVertical: 0.3, $Outside: true, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }

            //Flutter out Wind
            , { $Duration: 1800, $Delay: 30, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 5, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 5, $Reverse: true, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 2050, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InOutSine, $Top: $Jease$.$OutWave, $Clip: $Jease$.$InOutQuad }, $ScaleHorizontal: 1, $ScaleVertical: 0.2, $Outside: true, $Round: { $Top: 1.3} }

            //Collapse Stairs
            , { $Duration: 1200, $Delay: 30, $Cols: 8, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $SlideOut: true, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 2049, $Easing: $Jease$.$OutQuad }

            //Collapse Random
            , { $Duration: 1000, $Delay: 80, $Cols: 8, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: $Jease$.$OutQuad }

            //Vertical Chess Stripe
            , { $Duration: 1000, $Cols: 12, $FlyDirection: 8, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight, $ChessMode: { $Column: 12} }

            //Extrude out Stripe
            , { $Duration: 1000, $Delay: 40, $Cols: 12, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 2, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InOutExpo, $Opacity: $Jease$.$InOutQuad }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.2, $Opacity: 2, $Outside: true, $Round: { $Top: 0.5} }

            //Dominoes Stripe
            , { $Duration: 2000, $Delay: 60, $Cols: 15, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 8, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight, $Easing: $Jease$.$OutJump, $Round: { $Top: 1.5} }
            ];

            var options = {
                $AutoPlay: 1,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
                $Idle: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 0,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 1
                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                $SlideWidth: 990,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                $SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                $Cols: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $Align: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
                $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1
                                                                    //(Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
                $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                    $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
               },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2                                //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                }
            };

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
        };
    </script>
```

Please help me :) How can I make Autoplay work? :)

Comment: Oooh :) this is a magic place  :) just posted it and find a way :) my outer container truly havent any height and no style at all :) must apply some style to <div id="slider1_container"> and it will autoply my slides :)

Comment: Good to know you have got it worked!

Comment: Jssor, Thank you very much for this great slider!